# Change site links on Google Search

Tags: search, seo, google-search

I have a client that wants to change how his website appears in the Google search engine.
For example if you type in "stack overflow" into the Google search bar you get this result:

[image]

As I show in the image, what if I want to change the Python page to the PHP page.
How would I go about this.

I personally thought that Google just pulled the most relevant content and posted that, but there's got to be a way to change this. At least I would think so.

Any solution to this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google allows you to [demote a sitelink](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) but not modify one.

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however, to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's informative, compact, and avoids repetition.
>
> If you think that a sitelink URL is inappropriate or incorrect, you can demote it. Demoting a URL for a sitelink tells Google that you don't consider this URL a good sitelink candidate for a specific page on your site. Google doesn't guarantee that demoted URLs will never appear as a sitelink, but we do consider a demotion a strong hint that we'll try to honor when generating sitelinks.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. This is exactly what I was looking for.